# I need to rescind an override of OSX Gatekeeper for testing purposes

Tags: osx-gatekeeper

In osx montain lion, I need to test a download from an unauthorized developer.  I can use the "control click" method to tell gatekeeper to open the file, but the problem is that once I do this, gatekeeper remembers so I never see the open file dialogue again.  Is there any way that will allow me to return to the original unapproved state?